# How can i directly find the number of elements between any two iterator pointing to two different key in map without the for loop?

Tags: c++

How can i directly find the number of elements between any two iterator pointing to two different key in map without the for loop?

```
     #include <string>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <map>
     #include <utility>
     #include <iterator>
     #include <stdio.h>
     using namespace std;
     int main()
   {

     std::map<string, string> m;
     m.insert(pair< string, string>("4-2"," 61-7" ));
     m.insert(pair< string, string>("5-2"," 61-7" ));
     m.insert(pair< string, string>("5-3"," 61-7" ));
     m.insert(pair< string, string>("5-4"," 61-7" ));
     m.insert(pair< string, string>("5-5"," 61-7" ));
     m.insert(pair< string, string>("5-6"," 61-7" ));

     map<string, string>::iterator it4;
     map<string, string>::iterator it5;
     it4=m.find("5-2");
     it5=m.find("5-5");
     cout << " value of it4" << it4->first << it4->second <<  endl;
     cout << " value of it5" << it5->first << it5->second <<  endl;
     m.clear();
     getchar();

  }
```

My desired output is difference of elements betwen it5 and it4 which here is 2 as elements with key "5-3" and "5-4" lies between them . I dont want to iterate in for loop as in my case number of elements in map are large enough . And I have to regularly know the difference . using a for loop will take lot of time if two iterator are far away .

Comment: Why do you need the distance between elements anyway? That's a pretty unusual requirement when working with maps/sets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::distance(it4, it5)` from `<iterator>`. The cost will be linear in the result, though, so that doesn't really save you. If you must have quick access to this information, consider a Boost.Multi_index container so you can add a random-access index to your map.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I read it now after your post that its based on pointer arithmetic . So it must be efficient than iterating in a loop and finding the difference

Comment: It's not. It's exactly the same. `std::distance` uses pointer arithmetics *if you pass it pointers*. It uses the best method possible for the pointers you give it. For random access iterators (including pointers), it runs in constant time. For bidirectional iterators, such as those from `std::map`, it runs in linear time, and basically just wraps a loop similar to the one you have already

Comment: @Ritesh Kerrek's answer is correct, but it sounds like you misunderstood it

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements, it can't be done. `std::map` does not offer random-access iterators, which are necessary for determining iterator distance in constant time.

You can still use `std::distance`, but the cost will be the same as if you wrote the loop yourself.

If you need to generate this information more efficiently, you'll have to replace the map with a different data structure (or at least, augment it with some additional bookkeeping).

The only standard-library containers which have random-access iterators are the `vector`, `deque` and `array.

Comment: @Ritesh: `std::set` is in the same category as `std::map`, both are red-black trees and as such offer bidirectional iterators only (i.e., they only offer `++` and `--`).

Comment: Same as maps. A set is basically just a map with a key type but no value type.

Comment: @Xeo ohhh .. then it seems to be hard luck for me as we are using set in our implementation. Anyways do you know how is vector implemention different as vector and set both seems similar with just key ...Thanks for your previous reply

Comment: A vector is an array, and it's not automatically sorted. So vector iterators are basically just pointers. A map/set is a binary tree, and iterators have to traverse the nodes in that tree